# Select Record with Min value in a column and with specific value in another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
username     date       place      time
paolo        1/1/2001   milan      00:10.20
marco        1/1/2001   milan      00:11.40
paolo        1/1/2011   milan      00:12.20
paolo        1/1/2004   milan      00:10.50
```

I want to return the row with the lowest value of time for the username `paolo`:

```
paolo        1/1/2001   milan      00:10.20
```

I am trying with this query:

```
SELECT username,date,place,MIN(time) as record
FROM crono
WHERE username="paolo"
GROUP BY username,date,place
```

But it doesn't give the result I want.

Comment: Tip: store dates and times as a single entity, and using a correct data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM crono c
WHERE username = 'paolo'
ORDER BY time
LIMIT 1;
```

When using `GROUP BY`, never have columns in the `SELECT` that are not the arguments to the aggregation function and that are not in the `GROUP BY` -- unless you really, really, really know what you are doing.  Although this doesn't apply to your query, it is a common attempt at the solution.  Y

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a `Derived table` to calculate the `MIN(time)` and then `SELECT` it from the results of the `Derived table`.

```
SELECT username, date, place, record
FROM
(SELECT username, MIN(time) AS record
 FROM crono c
 GROUP BY username) recordselect
INNER JOIN crono c on recordselect.username= c.username
```